# Application background picture is showing on tablet but not on phone

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-studio, screen-size

I am working with `Android Studio`. I have one layout for all devices. Everything worked fine on `tablet` and also on `phone`. Then I changed my background picture and added layouts for `landscape`, `large-landscape` and `large-port`.

Now when I run the app on the tablet everything works fine and all the pictures in my app are being displayed as they should. When I run I on my phone instead of my picture the background is white but all the other pictures are displayed as they should.

I searched a while know and have no idea what I am doing wrong. Does anyone know what to do in this case?

Comment: Are you changed background image in main layout in layout folder?

Comment: My image is in the drawable folder. And it can´t be that I didn´t declare it the right way since the preview is correct.

Comment: Are you changed your layout background image in layout folder xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the file size of the image is too large?
Check the logcat output, if that is the problem there should be an error.
You can also try a smaller image